# In or on the opening/OST album?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Do we talk about songs *in* the OST album or *on* the OST album? Am I correct that we use *in* to mean songs included in the album, and *on* to mean songs listed on the album, and therefore both have roughly the same meaning?

And what does it mean when someone says "What are the chorus singing *on* the movie's opening?" Shouldn't *on* be *in* in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *in the OST album* or *on the OST album*.

"**in** the OST album" has the sense, as you mention, of being part of the group of songs that in total are the album.

"**on** the OST album" originates from the fact that songs are recorded onto the record platter.

In your example, you should write:

> What *is* the chorus singing **during** the movie's opening?

I don't think you can naturally use *on* or *in* here.